# How to install whats app on jailbreak iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak, install

I want to install WhatsApp Messenger on my iPod touch which is already jailbroken. Can anyone please help me install it step-by-step?

Comment: Maybe it's an option to use the 'search-bar' first.

Answer (score 3):

WhatsApp does not support the iPod touch (or other Wi-Fi only devices).

For more information, please see: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20951556

> WhatsApp is supported on most Android, BlackBerry, iPhone, Nokia, and
>   Windows smartphones.
>
> Other devices are not supported at this time. If you try to download
>   WhatsApp on an unsupported device, you will receive a message that
>   your device is not supported and you will not be able to download
>   WhatsApp. We currently **do not** support tablets, computers, or Wi-Fi
>   only devices, and do not plan to do so in the foreseeable future.